# How to get ALL column names using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the names of the fields (i.e. the structure of the table) in MySQL. I am using PHP to connect to MySQL.

This is my query:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database'
AND `TABLE_NAME`='Job Hunt'
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database' AND `TABLE_NAME`='Job Hunt'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

The output should read:

```
Array
    (
        [COLUMN_NAME] => id
        [COLUMN_NAME] => Company Name
        [COLUMN_NAME] => Address
        [COLUMN_NAME] => Date of Visit
    )
```

When I use the code above, the result only returns one row (or one "column header"):

```
Array
    (
        [COLUMN_NAME] => id
    )
```

How do I get an array of all the column names and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to either loop through the results and add them to an array or use mysqli_fetc_all() to get them all at once.

Comment: The array you're expecting is not possible. You can't have the same key in multiple array entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this to list down table columns.

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM YOURTABLENAME;`

OR

`DESC YOURTABLENAME`

In both the ways you can get your need done, whereas desc results you with associated column attributes as well.

**EDIT**

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME`) FROM`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`WHERE`TABLE_SCHEMA`='database' AND`TABLE_NAME`='Job Hunt'`

USE `GROUP_CONCAT` to achieve it, this will group all your column names into one record and in one column.

Find more aggregate functions here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html.

Comment: He'll still only get one column unless he puts the `fetch` code in a loop.